# VirtualBox Guest Additions on Rocky or Alma Linux 9.2

Tags: linux-kernel, software-installation, virtualbox

I've been trying to install VirtualBox Guest Additions
in VMs of both Rocky Linux and Alma Linux version 9.2
(with VirtualBox version 7.0.8). 
After running the install script, it states that it 'cannot verify if kernel modules and services were reloaded'.

It appears that the modules are being built, as the `vboxguest.ko`, `vboxsf.ko`, and `vboxvideo.ko` kernel objects are in the `/lib/modules/<kernel version>/misc` directory.

If I manually run `modprobe` on any of those, I get an error such as:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxguest': Exec format error.
```

From what I've seen, that error is typically a result of running a module built against a different kernel version than the one running, but I have verified that the kernel version in the `vboxadd-setup.log.1` matches `uname -r`.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the necessary packages for guest additions in the guest OS.

##### For Rocky Linux:

Gain root privileges:

```
sudo -s
```

Enable EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux):

```
dnf install epel-release  &&  dnf update --refresh
```

Install packages:

```
dnf install dkms kernel-devel kernel-headers gcc make bzip2 perl elfutils-libelf-devel
```

Source: [Install VirtualBox Guest Additions on Rocky Linux 9 - kifarunix.com](https://kifarunix.com/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-rocky-linux-9/).

Comment: This did not resolve the problem.